# Can the steps used to solve for the Echelon form result in different answers, or will they always yield the same answer?

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

Starting Matrix:
A= \begin{pmatrix}3 & -4 & 0 & 9\\
   2  & 4 &-1 & 0\\
   10 & 0 &-2 & -4 \end{pmatrix}

Given
=  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -1/5& 0\\
   0 & 1 &-3/20 &0\\
   0  &0 &   0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
My answer :
= \begin{pmatrix} 1&  0&  -1/5& -2/5\\
   0 & 1 &-3/20 &-9/10\\
   0  &0 &   0 &   1\end{pmatrix}

why my answer is different?Ive rechecked it alot of time Ive solved it correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can continue the process : the third line can be used to delete both last entries in your second and first lines. You have to do the following :
$L_2 \leftarrow L_2 + \frac{9}{10} L_3$ and $L_1 \leftarrow L_1 + \frac{2}{5} L_3$.
You will then get the correct answer.